# Python Handling Undeclared Variables

Tags: python, variables, declaration

In Python is it possible to avoid a variable (pre-) declaration to avoid a *NameError: name 'c' is not defined*:

```
a=5
if a==7:
    c=10
if c: print c
```

On a last line ***if c:*** simply verifies if variable '***c***' is not None. What can be used to check if 'c' variable even exist (or was pre-declared)?

Comment: If c only exists when the first `if` executes, why not put `print c` inside that `if` block?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, assign `None` to it first:

```
a = 5
c = None
if a == 7:
    c = 10
if c:
    print c
```

`None` tests as `False` in a boolean context, so `if c:` still works as written.

You could also catch the `NameError` exception:

```
try:
    print c
except NameError:
    pass
```

or use the [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) and [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) functions:

```
if 'c' in locals():
    # in a function

if 'c' in globals():
    # outside a function
```

but that's just plain ugly and unnecessary.

Comment: @Sputnix: Why? You can try and see if the name is available in `globals()` or `locals()`, but that is just plain ugly. To what goal should `c` not be pre-assigned?

Comment: The point is: if you don't know whether a name has been defined or not then there's probably a problem with your code. Good code is made of small simple functions and avoids globals as much as possible, so you _should_ know. If you don't, refactor your code.

Answer (score 6):

You could catch the exception.

```
a = 5
if a == 7:
    c = 10
try:
    print c
except NameError:
    pass
```

Comment: this seems like the best answer in my opinion, I'm using this for retrieveing contants from a config file and making sure that it's setup properly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`locals`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#locals) to check if the variable is in the local scope:

```
>>> c = 1
>>> locals()
{'__doc__': None, 'c': 1, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__package__': None}
>>> 'c' in locals()
True
>>>
```

You may also be interested in [`globals`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#globals).

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why you would need a variable under certain circumstances and not others, but the simplest thing is to move the `print` into the scope `c` is assigned in:

```
if a == 7:
    c = 10
    print(c)
```

or to remove the variable entirely:

```
if a == 7:
    print(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python3 and despite Martijn thinking that it is ugly:
If you know the variable is a global:

```
if globals().get('abc'): print (True)
```

if you know that it is local:

```
if locals().get('abc'): print (True)
```